# Nginx Rewrite Issue to External link

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm trying to set up a permanent redirect from

```
http://domain.com/member/blog_post_view.php?postId=1
```

to

```
http://blog.domain.com/friendly-url-here
```

The source URL contains both a ? and an = which I think might be the cause but am unsure.

I've tried all sorts of nginx suggestiosn including the one below but can't seem to get the redirection to work and hoped someone can point me in the right direction.

```
location  /blog_post_view.php?postId=1 {
   rewrite "/blog_post_view.php\?postId\=1" http://blog.domain.com/friendly-url-here permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That part of request line starting from the question mark is called [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), while the `location` directive matches only path part of URI.

You should use $arg_* variable instead:

```
location =/blog_post_view.php {
    if ($arg_postId = 1) {
        return 301 http://blog.domain.com/friendly-url-here;
    }
}
```

Reference:

- http://nginx.org/r/location
- http://nginx.org/r/if
- [Embedded Variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables)

Comment: hmmm, i understand what you say about the query string. I thought would be an issue.
Unfortunately that snippet didn't work for me

Comment: It seems I needed to include the full path in the location (after the domain name).
Once I used /member/blog_post_view.php all is working as I expected.
Just a little gotcha for a newbie - I wrongly presumed Nginx would have identified and matched against a partial URL but seems not.
Thanks to VBart for his wonderful help.